# Three days in Montenegro, looking for good beaches, where should we go?

Tags: buses, beaches, montenegro

I'm planning to stay three days in Montenegro. I'm looking for fine beaches and I'm travelling by bus. I've been to Budva earlier in my holiday and it was ok, but I'd like something less "commercial" and more "natural".

I've read around a little and I understood that Kotor is not good for swimming. I was considering Ulcinj since I read that there are some good beaches over there and it's not too "commercial". I could consider Budva only if someone tells me that there are some interesting things around there to do like excursions ... but remember that I travel by bus and so my budget is limited.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perast was the best beach for me (15 km from Kotor).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Ulcinj** county has the best beaches in Montenegro. The good beaches are several km outside the city towards the Albanian border. Local transport should be frequent during the day, and you can stay either at the beach or in the Ulcinj city.

Velika Plaza (Large Beach) is 10km long, uncrowded with nice sand and a long shallow part. Ada Bojana is an island at a river estuary, the beach is clothing-optional, has some nice waves.

Ulcinj also has an old town on a steep hill (an Ottoman fortress, different than Venetian ones elsewhere). Accommodation prices are slightly better than elsewhere.

Budva and Bay of Kotor have great scenery, old towns and some nightlife. Unfortunately, the beaches are crowded and rather unimpressive (relatively small, not much sand, mostly uncomfortable pebbles, sharp and deep drop-off).

If you're traveling by bus, you can go to Kotor first, spend a few hours there (perhaps take a tour of the bay and the fortress), and then take a local bus down to Ulcinj (~2-3h bus ride).

Comment: I did exactly as you suggested and it was a really nice trip! :)

Answer (score 8):

While as you've mentioned, Budva has the main tourist areas with nice beaches and so on, the Bay of Kotor is considered one of the most beautiful bays in Europe, and has the UNESCO World Heritage Sites of Perast and Kotor, plus other typically Mediterranean towns.  Kotor especially looks spectacular with the deepest natural fjord in the entire Mediterranean.  Sure, these aren't traditional beaches but you'll still have the natural beauty and climate.

You can consider the South Coast, of course, for beaches.  Ulcinj has several nice beach spots, and has many easy ways in by bus.  It's popular with people from Kosovo, and also is meant to have some of the most beautiful girls in the Balkans ;)  The highlighted beach here is the "Great Beach" or Velika Plaža - a 12km long beach included in the NYTimes 2010 list of "[The 31 Places to go in 2010](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/01/10/travel/10places.html?pagewanted=2&ref=travel)".

Finally, the nicely named Bar is also on the South Coast, and is home to the oldest olive tree in the world (random fact), and great beaches 30 min walk away in Susanj.

Comment: Bar also has a large old town / walled fortress (Stari Bar), about 5-10 km from the center. Tourist seldom visit that part, so it is more authentic and quiet than Budva/Kotor old towns.

Answer (score 7):

Also, for people who would like to see UNESCO World Heritage Site Kotor Old Town and at same time would like to be at a nice beach, I would suggest beach Plavi Horizonti that is 8km from Kotor and usually people from Kotor and Tivat visit this beach, because of its nice sand and beautiful nature. It is a famous place among people that want to get away from places like Budva and lots of noise.